# Outlook 2013 generates invalid attachment ID for forwarded emails, causing the EWS GetAttachment() operation to fail

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, attachment

Can someone please confirm if this is a product bug in Outlook 2013 (`15.0.5023.1000, 64-bit`), where Outlook 2013 generates invalid `attachmentID` for attachment(s) that are in the FORWARDED email.

Furthermore, when the exact same forwarded email is accessed via Outlook 2016, everything works fine and has a valid `attachmentID`. Emails that are forwarded using Outlook 2016 work fine both, in Outlook 2013 as well as Outlook 2016. In general the `attachmentID` for a given attachment in outlook 2013 is same as the `attachmentID` for the same attachment in Outlook 2016. Only in the case of emails forwarded using Outlook 2013, the attachment IDs differ where the `attachmentID` in outlook 2013 is invalid but the one in Outlook 2016 is valid

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="669" MinorBuildNumber="32" Version="V2016_07_13" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <m:GetAttachmentResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <m:MessageText>The specified attachment Id is invalid.</m:MessageText>
          <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidAttachmentId</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          <m:Attachments />
        </m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetAttachmentResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Had you found a solution ? facing the same problem ATM